# In-place Javascript editing addon

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-addon, firebug

Is there any inplace editing addon for Javascript..something like firebug which is very useful for Instant CSS editing and preview, but does not allow inplace JS editing..So, is there any tool or addon where we can instantly update and see Javascript changes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the console in Firebug. You can type javascript commands in the console that will immediately execute.

You'll notice too in the console that on the far right hand side there's an option to open the command editor which allows you to write multiple lines of javascript before executing.

Comment: So is the command editor option similar to inplace editing like CSS ?

Comment: It's different in that you're not editing in place scripts on the page, but it's similar in that you can dynamically write and run javascript on the page. The best way to understand it is just to open it up and play around with it a bit.